Interpret ℒight
Interpreting ℒight is easy since all you do is print # indefinitely with no input.
The difference i have is that this prints a different symbol. Which is kind of useless imo

Fourth time's the charm
Remember we have a Sandbox to run things by first! It's an excellent way to iron out other kinks in a challenge, too.

Hi, you might also enjoy the chat room. It's a good place for mini challenges that might not fit on the main site (C.M.C.) or generally to talk about the languages you are working on. Lots of language designers in there

@mousetail'he-him' if i had 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network then I could chat there

JAGL, 5 bytes
@#|#~

Try it online
